# XML data from one Excel cell to new XML file

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, xml

In A1, A2, A3... A16000 I have the entire context of a XML in one cell.

*Example: The entire XML for one invoice is in A1, the next invoice in A2 and so on.*

How could I save the context of each cell, into seperate XML files?

I tried to extract the relevant data directly from the cell using "filterxml", but I ran into trouble when the inovice contained multiples item lines.

Comment: Do you have sample code of what you have tried?

Comment: =FILTRERXML($A2;B$1) - In B1 I have "//cac:Item/cbc:Description". I can make it an array, and then it pulls all the information, but not all invoices have the same amount of lines.

Comment: `FILTERXML` isn't a standard function in Excel, I'm afraid we can't help with you with it without knowing it. Best option would be to contact it's author.

Comment: It looks like [FILTERXML](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FILTERXML-function-4DF72EFC-11EC-4951-86F5-C1374812F5B7) is a function available in selected versions of Excel starting with 2013.  FILTRERXML is one of the function language translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the entire XML is indeed a valid XML format and you simply need to export each cell as it's own file, you could use the following VBA:

```
Sub ExportCellsToXMLFiles()
    On Error GoTo err:
    Dim OutputFolder: OutputFolder = "D:\Test\XML\" 'Specify a valid dir to output to - make sure you include the trailing slash.
    Dim objFSO: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim objFile
    Dim Count: Count = 1 'Row number to start on
    Do
        Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(OutputFolder & "Invoice_" & Count & ".xml", False, True) ' You can change the file names if needed here
        objFile.Write (Cells(Count, 1).Value)
        objFile.Close
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(Count, 1).Value)

err:
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

EDIT: I think certain programs may not be interpreting it correctly as they expect a UTF-8 charset. Try this code instead:

```
Sub ExportCellsToXMLFiles()
    On Error GoTo err:
    Dim OutputFolder: OutputFolder = "D:\Test\XML\"
    Dim fsT As Object
    Dim Count: Count = 1
    Do
        Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        fsT.Type = 2
        fsT.Charset = "utf-8"
        fsT.Open
        fsT.WriteText (Cells(Count, 1).Value)
        fsT.SaveToFile OutputFolder & "Invoice_" & Count & ".xml", 2
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(Count, 1).Value)

err:
    Set fsT = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I receive a parse error. So it was probably not a valid XML. I will attach an example of the content of a single cell

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Invoice xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 UBL-Invoice-2.0.xsd" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2" xmlns:sdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SpecializedDatatypes-2"

Comment: @ClaesThaysen Edit it into your question :) Too long for a comment

Comment: @ClaesThaysen I just tested it in an XML editor and it seems to read it fine? http://i.imgur.com/gyUNLvC.jpg

Comment: Thank you for heldping. I have shared an example via dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/s/59ae2nj8oxegm9s/Invoices.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: @ClaesThaysen Ran the macro over it, got 10 XML files, each of them seem to open fine? http://imgur.com/2fCFsKH.jpg - What are you trying to open them in...?

Comment: I get this error. http://imgur.com/tXXXkwK

Comment: @ClaesThaysen That's because it's not using Unicode encoding, not that it can't read it but that when you save it it'll change the encoding. I've amended the VBA slightly to output in UTF from the start, try it again.

Comment: Almost there! If I try to import the file directly in Excel, I get a parse-error. If I open the file in a text editor, copy the text and into a new XML file in Visual Studio and then import that file in Excel, all is good.

Comment: @ClaesThaysen I see what is happening. Try the second chunk of VBA I just added to the answer instead.

Comment: Great! But for some reason invoice number 4 and 10 fail?

Comment: Never mind. Those cells look weird to begin with. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: @ClaesThaysen Yes, it looks like they're broken in Excel too, I think they're too long for the cell, one has a BASE64 encoded PDF in it.

Comment: @Jonno, +1 for the perfect answer. I'm using Excel 2016 and only the first chunk of VBA code worked for me. I tried the second one, but it did not work. May I ask if the two codes are for different Excel environments?

Comment: @Prasanna That's strange, I used Excel 2016 to test it. Does it give you an error message? (You might need to remove the `On Error...` line to see it)

Comment: @Jonno. No errors. When I run the macro, it just does nothing. Strange to me too. May be you should describe why there are two different code blocks to accomplish the same task - just suggesting. BTW, mine is Windows 10 (if that would help)

Comment: @Prasanna I'm using Windows 10 too. Did you remove the `On Error` line, then you should get an error code. Other wise I don't know if you may have missed something on setting the folder path, it may be working just not in the location you expected! The difference in code blocks is the second explicitly uses UTF-8 (I did put a line between the two with a brief explanation, but maybe it could be clearer!)